# How to get latest doc from elasticsearch in grafana?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am using grafana to show some data stored in elasticsearch.

I want to know if it is possible to get some latest data (like 10 docs, use a timestamp field to judge) from elasticsearch and show in a table without any aggregation.

For example.

doc saved in elasticsearch like.

```
{
    timestamp: 1453369151115,
    status: true,
    runTime: 5327420525,
    name: "importUserAgent",
    ts: "2016-01-21T17:39:11",
    hostname: "site-211",
    app_id: "15"
}

{
    timestamp: 1453369145785,
    status: true,
    runTime: 369315816,
    name: "dailyService",
    ts: "2016-01-21T17:39:05",
    hostname: "site-211",
    app_id: "15"
}
```

and to show like

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use the time range selection to get the required of particular time stamp

[image]